# MySQL 5.7: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause"

Tags: mysql

This is a bit different than the normal "You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause" questions. I know I need to create a temp table as part of the query to get around that, but I'm doing that as shown below and still getting that error.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'filename.csv' 
INTO TABLE campaigner.areas 
CHARACTER SET latin1 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(abbr, fips_code, name) 
SET area_type_id    = @STATE_TYPE_ID,
 description     = NULL,
 gnis_feature_id = NULL,
 parent_id       = (SELECT c.country_id FROM (SELECT country_id,country_abbr FROM campaigner.countries_v) AS c WHERE c.country_abbr = 'US'),
 latitude        = NULL,
 longitude       = NULL;
```

Here's the definition of countries_v, which, as you can see, does use the areas table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW campaigner.countries_v (country_id, country_abbr, country_name, fips_code) AS
            SELECT c.country_id, ca.abbr, ca.name, ca.fips_code
              FROM campaigner.countries c
         LEFT JOIN campaigner.areas     ca  ON c.country_id  = ca.area_id;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Update: This works in MySQL 5.6

Comment: And I found a comment in another page that I think explains why it works in 5.6 and not in 5.7: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause
"However, beware that from MySQL 5.7.6 and onward, the optimiser may optimise out the subquery, and still give you the error. Luckily, the optimizer_switch variable can be used to switch off this behaviour; although I couldn't recommend doing this as anything more than a short term fix, or for small one-off tasks."

Answer (score 2):

You are inserting data into the table campaigner.areas wich you also use in the view, thats the problem.

Comment: Except that all of the solutions I see say that using the temp table bypasses that problem.

Answer (score 1):

And I found a comment in another page that I think explains why it works in 5.6 and not in 5.7: stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/… "However, beware that from MySQL 5.7.6 and onward, the optimiser may optimise out the subquery, and still give you the error. Luckily, the optimizer_switch variable can be used to switch off this behaviour; although I couldn't recommend doing this as anything more than a short term fix, or for small one-off tasks." 
So I am using SET optimizer_switch = 'derived_merge=off';

Comment: Still having problems. I've tried setting the optimizer_switch, using DISTINCT and LIMIT in the subquery, to no avail. Could it be that being part of a LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE statement is causing all these things to be ignored?